# Clicking AJAX links? Watir

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, watir

SOLVED:

I figured out my problem with this little piece of code:

```
b.link(id: 'm_wm_w5_m_lv_ctrl1_m_lnkWatch').fire_event :click
```

QUESTION:

I am having trouble clicking AJAX links with Watir.

Here is what I want to click.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du1js.png

This is what HTML looks like

```
<a id="m_wm_w5_m_lv_ctrl1_m_lnkWatch" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m_wm$w5$m_lv$ctrl1$m_lnkWatch','')" 
style="white-space:nowrap; font-size:11px;">New Listing (160)</a></td>
```

So, in Watir, I used the following to click to think

```
b.link(id: 'm_wm_w5_m_lv_ctrl1_m_lnkWatch').click
```

But when I do that, I get this CSS pop up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApDFj.png

The HTML for close button on the pop up is:

```
<div id="NewsDetailDismissNew" class="btn mtx-btn-confirm enabled" title="Close">Close</div>
```

But when I use this in Watir

```
b.div(id: 'NewsDetailDismissNew').click
```

Nothing happens.

I did find some javascript that seems to correspond with the buttons

```
<!--<div class="container" >-->
    <script>
    var cvMarkAsRead=function(  ){ return "Mark as Read"; };
</script>
    <script>
    var cvClose=function(  ){ return "Close"; }; //This is closes the CSS pop up as far as I can tell
</script>
    <script>
    var cvOK=function(  ){ return "OK"; };
</script>
    <script>
    var cvDismiss=function(  ){ return "I've Read This"; };
</script>
    <script>
    var cvPreview=function(  ){ return "Print Preview"; };
</script>   

    <!-- End NewsDetail modal -->
```

My question to you guys is

1. How can I click "New Listings" in Watir?
2. How can I click the "Close" button on the pop up?

I see that the link has some javascript, but I am not familiar enough with Watir to use `b.execute_script` successfully. I read the documentation. I am not understanding it and the examples provided are not similar enough to my problem for me to learn by practicing or copying.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't have to bother about that JavaScript associated with that button. You have clicked the new Listings, eh? As a result that pop up is showing up, no? Did you get any error while you click that pop up? Can you give me url so that I can check it out?

Comment: The URL requires a private log in that was created for me under the agreement that I cannot share it.  I apologize.

Is there a way that I can use something like 
```
b.execute_script('cvClose')
``` 
to close the pop up? I have tried that and it did not work. I do not get an error when It try that. I only get 'nil'

Comment: It's unclear, do you EXPECT to get the popup when you click the link? What exactly is your expectation vs result?

Comment: @Rajagopalan I have clicked new listings in two ways. The first was to click by b.link(text: /New Listings/).click because the number is dynamic. It is not always the same. I have also tried clicking by id using b.link(id: 'm_wm_w5_m_lv_ctrl1_m_lnkWatch').click. I do not get any errors. What I do get is a CSS pop up window when I try to click the link "New Listings".

Comment: Are you able to click the new listings via program?

Comment: @Beartech I do not expect the pop up. I click the ID for New Listings and I got the pop up. Very weird.

What I expect to happen is for a list to be generated via AJAX. In this case, it would be a lis of 160 items.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I can click new listings in irb and the program, but I get the pop up that I cannot seem to close. Very strange.

Comment: Do not update the comment again and again because I have no way of knowing whether you updated, I will not get any notification for that, so start writing another comment as a reply to this comment. So new listings are being clicked now, Can you try to click that manually and check whether you are getting the same pop up?

Comment: Okay, check manually and let me know whether you get the same pop up?

Comment: @Rajagopalan When I click it manually, I do not get the same pop up. I just realized that the pop up I am getting is the 3rd item in the "News & Alerts" section. I am inspecting that element. It does not share the same ID as the ID for "New Listings".

Comment: Okay write this code and see what's the count `p b.links(id: 'm_wm_w5_m_lv_ctrl1_m_lnkWatch').count`

Comment: @Rajagopalan Count of 1

Comment: If it is count of 1 then it can't click anywhere other than new listings, it won't go to the third link in the news and alert section. By the way I am giving up now because I can't guess anymore without the url. Good luck.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Thank you for your help thus far. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I found the solution and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of code below solves my problem. It clinks on `New Listing` and successfully loads all the new listings as well as avoids triggering that erroneous CSS pop up.

I think what this code does is activate the javascript by clicking the link.

I successfully clicked this link

```
<a id="m_wm_w5_m_lv_ctrl1_m_lnkWatch" href="javascript:__doPostBack('m_wm$w5$m_lv$ctrl1$m_lnkWatch','')" 
style="white-space:nowrap; font-size:11px;">New Listing (160)</a>
```

By using this code in Watir:

```
b.link(id: 'm_wm_w5_m_lv_ctrl1_m_lnkWatch').fire_event :click
```

Comment: `fire_event` uses Javascript click, Javascript would not stimulate actual user click. Infact it would even wait for page_load If page has to load after the click. Driver click takes care of lot of things before and after the click. It's okay now if it's working now. But always use Driver click, if it's not working, then you can go for javascript click or action builder click.